# Implementing Amazon Wishlist Like Undo in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-experience

I'm thinking of implementing an "Amazon Wishlist-ish" undo functionality to my app.

I mean...
[image: Before]

> then click 'Delete Item'

[image: After]

> by clicking 'Undo', the deletion appears to be canceled

[image: Before]

My list controller is currently looking like this,

```
function ListsController($scope, List) {↲                                                                                     
  List.get({}, function(lists) {
  $scope.lists = lists.objects;
  $scope.delete_list = function(index) {
    var isConfirmed = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?');
    if (isConfirmed) {      
      var targetlist = $scope.lists[index];
      List.delete({ listId: targetlist.id },
      function(list) {
        $scope.lists.splice(index, 1);
      }
      )
    }
  } 
 });
};
```

But I wanna enable undo feature as I said.

What is the best way to do that in angular js?

Answer (score 1):

I can't give an exact example without seeing what the `List` service does, but I think your best bet is to keep track of removed items in another scope variable and if the undo is clicked you just add it back to lists.

Maybe something like:

```
$scope.deleted_lists = [];
$scope.delete_list = function(index) {
  var isConfirmed = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?');
  if (isConfirmed) {      
    var targetlist = $scope.lists[index];
    List.delete({ listId: targetlist.id }, function(list) {
      $scope.deleted_lists.concat($scope.lists.splice(index, 1));
    });
  }
};
```

Then you can use an ng-repeat (if you want multiple undos) to display the deleted items and a click on the undo button could simply add the item back to the list via .push().

Comment: Here is [a very rudimentary demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tVFLzKlAoZwSCMDiKfUc?p=preview) of this concept of taking the results of an array splice and storing them somewhere else that allows for a reverse of action later. You will quickly see its limitations, which exhibit the point that although undo/redo is not rocket science, you have to do some work to set it up if it is to be truly useful.

Comment: @theJoeBiz Thanks. I've tried that aproach, but I couldn't figure out how can I push html says like `<p><a href=''>undo</a></p>` in the exact position where the deleted list was located.